# Unexpected "100 continue"

Tags: windows-server-2003, proxy, http

I have 2 servers (using windows server 2003) that communicates using .Net remoting. For some architectural reasons, I have a proxy between those 2 servers, that removes the "Expect: 100-continue" header from the request that is sent from one server to another. The problem is, that when the proxy sends the message to the second server without this header, the destination server responses with "100 continue". This behavior causes us many problems, since the proxy discards the whole http conversation, when it gets "100 continue".
I googled this issue, and I found that there was a bug in windows server 2003 SP1, which was supposed to be fixed in SP2, but after I installed it, the problem still remains.
Does anyone knows how to fix it, or to configure http.sys not to send the "100 continue"?

Answer (score 1):

try forcing http/1.0 communication [ either by reconfiguring proxy, changing the client code or http server configuration ]. this will degrade the performance [ if you use for instance keep-alive ] but should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Many proxy servers are using HTTP 1.0.  When the software at either end tries to use 1.1 capabilities things start to get crazy.

In some cases where negotiation is required, the client and the server can both agree that 1.1 is the proper protocol (and the proxy server pretends to go along).  Then when 1.1 level communication actually occurs, the proxy server strips out things it doesn't understand.

Switching to 1.0 from the client is usually the easiest way to get reliable results.

If you are using web services, this may require a helper class to modify the request.  If this is what you're doing I'll look up an example.